# Javascript property is shows undefined when used as default state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I fetched some content via `useEffect` to be used as a default state in my app. Please see code below:

```
const id = props.match.params.id;
const classes = UseStyles();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchCategories()), []);
const categories = useSelector((state) => state).generalReducer.category;

useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchBusinessDetail(id)), []);
const business = useSelector((state) => state).generalReducer.businessDetail;
console.log(business);

console.log(business.name);
let defaultState = {
  name: business.name,
  description: business.description,
  url: business.url,
  phone: business.phone,
  address: business.address,
  category_id: [],
  email: business.email,
  image: "",
};

const [formState, setFormState] = useState(defaultState);
console.log(formState);
```

`console.log(business)` and `console.log(business.name)` gave expected results however, `console.log(formState)` gives undefined values like this:

```
{
  // ...
  image: "";
  name: undefined;
  phone: undefined;
  url: undefined;
}
```

How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`useState(initialState)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), `initialState` will be the value on **initial render**.

> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

Because you **fetching** the `defaultState`, its initial value is what you get from **redux store**:

```
// business values are values from redux store
let defaultState = {name: business.name, description: business.description, url:business.url, phone:business.phone, address: business.address, category_id: [], email:business.email, image:''  };
```

Usually, you update the state **after you done fetching**:

```
const businessSelector = state => state.generalReducer.businessDetail;

const business = useSelector(businessSelector);

// Fetch and update `business` above.
useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchBusinessDetail(id)), []);

// `business` get new values and update the form.
useEffect(() => {
  setFormState(business);
}, [business]);
```

Comment: Yes, after fetching data, he must set it using `setFormState`, you are right, can you plezse explain about `useSelector((state) => state).generalReducer.businessDetail;` what this code does?

Comment: Typo from OP question, it should be a selector